# How can I make this page redirect after executing the code?

Tags: php

How can I make this page redirect after executing the code? SO I have this snippet, I want it to verify some stuff in an if statement, Instert stuff into the databse if it is true and then redirect to another page that executes other code. This what I've tried so far:

```
 if ( x = y) {


   $Connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "something", "password", "some");
    // Check connection
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
   }

     $sql="UPDATE sometable SET paid = True,  sessionid = 'someid' WHERE sessionid = 'originalid' ";

     $query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);


     echo '<script type="text/javascript">
     window.location = "http://jump.com"
     </script>';
 }

else{

  exit(); // exit script
```

It does everything but the reditrect part. the page it redirects to is suppose to execute some other code that isn't happening. I know the code is correct because when i go to it manually , it executes

Comment: Don't use JavaScript here; just do `header("Location: http://salsero.us/endpoint");`.  Also, you have `if (x = y) {`. If you are trying to check equality, this should be something like `if ($x == $y) {`. You also have an unmatched `{` for your `else`, so I assume this is not your full code; otherwise, you will get a parser error.

Comment: Dont' use header("Location: http://salsero.us/endpoint");
It will through error "Header already sent" Due to echo statement above it.

Comment: I got an error statement like confused said.

Answer (score 0):

Try redirecting with this (PHP-code) instead:

```
header("Location: http://salsero.us/endpoint");
```

You need to have your javascript-code in a window onload event.

```
window.onload = function() {
 window.location = "http://salsero.us/endpoint"
};
```

But I would opt for the first solution because it's all serverside, and if you just can do it in the server
do it there. Keep it simple :)

Comment: This would be for onload, I want it to happen after the code has run

Answer (score 0):

you have some errors in your code I correct most of the them eg - if(x=y) and you not use any error handling code,

**Try with following code sample.**

```
if ( x == y) {


    $Connection = mysqli_connect("localhost", "salsacart", "78reguyer748", "salss");
    // Check connection
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      exit;
   }

   try{
     $sql="UPDATE sometable SET paid = True,  sessionid = 'someid' WHERE sessionid = 'originalid' ";

     $query = mysqli_query($Connection, $sql);
   }catch(Exception $e){
       echo "Update Failed...!";
       exit;
   }


     echo ' <script>
     window.location = "http://salsero.us/endpoint"
     </script>';
 }

else{

  exit(); // exit script
```